# Расстояние между иконкой и текстов в bottomnavigationview

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Мне нужно сократить расстояние между иконкой и текстом, но я не понимаю как это сделать.
[image: В фигме]

Я увеличил высоту итема в соответствии с макетом.

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">83dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">220dp</dimen>
```

Вот мой код навигации:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottomnavigation_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomnavigation_bg"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemIconSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
```

И вот как это всё выглядит:
[image: <t]

Comment: а размеры иконки какие?

Comment: Размер иконки 18х18

Comment: Там отступ у текста, я пытался даже саму картинку менять. Тоесть через xml сверху отступы делать. Но она упирается в отступ у текста.

Comment: поставьте размер 24*24, я думаю ситуация изменится